# gdb convenience variable strcat

Tags: c, linux, gdb

I want to use convenience variables to collect a list of things.  I couldn't find anything about string concactenation of convenience variables.  So I tried some things out.

check this out:

```
(gdb) set $foo="foo"
(gdb) p $foo
$45 = 0x84c7fd8 "foo"
(gdb) call strcat($foo,"bar")
$46 = 139231192
(gdb) p $foo
$47 = 0x84c7fd8 "foobar"
```

Ok so i tried harder to crash it:

```
(gdb) set $foo="foo"
(gdb) set $bar="blue"
(gdb) p $foo
$48 = 0x85d9100 "foo"
(gdb) p $bar
$49 = 0x83cd1e8 "blue"
(gdb) call memset($foo,' ',100000)
$50 = 140349696
(gdb) call strlen($foo)
$51 = 100001
(gdb) p $foo
$52 = 0x85d9100 ' ' <repeats 200 times>...
(gdb) p $bar
$53 = 0x83cd1e8 "blue"
```

I'm getting lucky.

Yep:

```
(gdb) call sprintf($foo, "%d %d %d\n", 1,2,3)
*** glibc detected *** /dev_tools/base/LOCAL-4.0.8_RHEL5.4/bin/sicstus: malloc(): memory corruption: 0x085e8790 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6[0x9da250]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_malloc+0x67)[0x9dbd87]
/lib/libc.so.6(__libc_memalign+0x12b)[0x9dc01b]
/lib/ld-linux.so.2(malloc+0x25)[0x966705]
/dev_tools/base/LOCAL-4.0.8_RHEL5.4/bin/sicstus[0x80486f0]
[0xa]
======= Memory map: ========
00952000-0096c000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 34185                              /lib/ld-2.5.so
0096c000-0096d000 r--p 00019000 fd:00 34185                              /lib/ld-2.5.so
0096d000-0096e000 rw-p 0001a000 fd:00 34185                              /lib/ld-2.5.so
00970000-00aaf000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 34194                              /lib/libc-2.5.so
00aaf000-00ab0000 ---p 0013f000 fd:00 34194                              /lib/libc-2.5.so
```

Maybe this is a better way to do it:

```
(gdb) set $foo=(char*)malloc(100000)
(gdb) p $foo
$83 = 0xf0d18bd0 ""
(gdb) call memset($foo,' ',100000)
$84 = -254702640
(gdb) set $foo[99999]=0
(gdb) call strlen($foo)
$85 = 99999
(gdb) set $foo[0]=0
(gdb) call strcat($foo,"12345")
$86 = -254702640
(gdb) call strcat($foo,"12345")
$87 = -254702640
(gdb) p $foo
$88 = 0xf0d18bd0 "1234512345"
```

Anyone got a better idea?

**EDIT**

Thanks to Employed Russian, this works:

```
2       breakpoint     keep y   0xf1b451ee in xxx at yyy.c:230
        breakpoint already hit 30 times
        silent
        set logging on
        p szFileName
        set logging off
        cont
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is some stuff that worked with malloc:

```
1       breakpoint     keep y   0xf1ac915f in xxx at yyy:346
        breakpoint already hit 334 times
        silent
        call sprintf($foo+strlen($foo),"%.3s %.4s %lf\n", s1, s2, (p->Amts[0].lfAmt > 0.01) ? p->Amts[0].lfAmt : p->Amts[1].lfAmt)
        cont
```

before a run, I would do this:

```
(gdb) set $foo=(char*)malloc(100000)
(gdb) set $foo[0]=0
```

Comment: Since `sprintf` was triggering the crash previously, what happens when you call `sprintf` on your `malloc`'d $foo?

Comment: The malloc'd foo works great.  No problems!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
(gdb) set $foo="foo"
```

effectively executes `$foo = strdup("foo")` in the inferior (being debugged) process.

This:

```
(gdb) call strcat($foo,"bar")
```

corrupts heap in the inferior. It didn't crash by pure luck.

> Anyone got a better idea?

There is no better idea.

Also, I've never needed to collect things in that fashion. It seems to me that you could achieve the same result in a much more flexible way by either running GDB in emacs, or just cut/pasting the values you need into an editor buffer.

Comment: 12000 items.  After collecting them in $foo I used gdb logging to dump them to a file.  Where I could run sort and wc etc.

Comment: @johnnycrash why not use GDB logging to dump the items to the file in the first place? I.e. why do you need to accumulate them into a string first?

Comment: That might be the better idea.  Lots of things print to stdio, so I would have to turn logging on and off but I will see if that doesn't slow down too much.